# Data duplicates using Do While Loop in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010, do-while

I just wanted to ask why my data duplicates and how can I prevent it?

**NOTE:** my SQL query are working properly, the only problem is that every data it saves are duplicated based on the last value of ctr

Here is my code:

```
  For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvReportFormat2.Items
            Dim count = lvReportFormat2.Items.Count
            Dim ctr = 0
            Dim orderby = 0

            label.Text = lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(4).Text

            Do While ctr < count
                Label1.Text = lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(4).Text
                Execute("INSERT INTO tblrptChad (accountcode,accountdesc,Type,class,Orderby,ReportType,Formula,Show)VALUES ('" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(0).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(0).Text, "NULL") & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(1).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(1).Text, "NULL") & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(2).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(2).Text, "NULL") & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(3).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(3).Text, "NULL") & "','" & orderby & "','" & Val(IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(5).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, Val(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(5).Text), 0)) & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(6).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(6).Text, "NULL") & "','" & Val(IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(7).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, Val(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(7).Text), 0)) & "')")
                ctr = ctr + 1
                orderby = orderby + 1
            Loop


        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting duplicates of your records because you loop two times on the Items collection of your ListView. A first time with the `foreach lvi ... Next` statement and a second time with the `Do While loop`

A full answer to your question would require to introduce you to parameterized queries, but this involves to change radically your Execute method.
So for the immediate answer

```
Dim orderby = 0
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvReportFormat2.Items

    Label1.Text = lvi.SubItems(4).Text
    Execute("INSERT INTO tblrptChad "& _
    "(accountcode,accountdesc,Type,class,Orderby," & _
    "ReportType,Formula,Show) VALUES " & _
    "('" & _
       If(lvi.SubItems(0).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, _ 
           lvi.SubItems(0).Text, "NULL") & "','" & _ 
       If(lvi.SubItems(1).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, _
           lvi.SubItems(1).Text, "NULL") & "','" & _
       If(lvi.SubItems(2).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, _
           lvi.SubItems(2).Text, "NULL") & "','" & _
       If(lvi.SubItems(3).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, _
           lvi.SubItems(3).Text, "NULL") & "','" & _
       orderby & "','" & _
       Val(If(lvi.SubItems(5).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, _
           Val(lvi.SubItems(5).Text), 0)) & "','" & _
       If(lvi.SubItems(6).Text IsNot DBNull.Value,  _
           lvi.SubItems(6).Text, "NULL") & "','" & _
       Val(If(lvi.SubItems(7).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, _
           Val(lvi.SubItems(7).Text), 0)) & "')")
   orderby = orderby + 1
Next
```

`lvi` in the for each is the `ListViewItem` currently indexed.
This means that `lvi is lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr)`

As a side note, I am pretty sure that a string property like `SubItems(x).Text` cannot be a DBNull value, so all these IIF are pretty useless and can be removed. I let you try it.

Said that, you really should look at [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) to simplify your command text removing all those string concatenations that are error prone to get it right (for example, did yuo check what happens if one of your subitems contains a text with an apostrophe?) and are the main vector for [Sql Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

Answer (score 0):

```
TO SOLVE THE PROBLE YOU JUST NEED TO ADD "EXIT SUB" OUTSIDE THE LOOP

For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvReportFormat2.Items
            Dim count = lvReportFormat2.Items.Count
            Dim ctr = 0
            Dim orderby = 0

            label.Text = lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(4).Text

            Do While ctr < count
                Label1.Text = lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(4).Text
                Execute("INSERT INTO tblrptChad (accountcode,accountdesc,Type,class,Orderby,ReportType,Formula,Show)VALUES ('" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(0).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(0).Text, "NULL") & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(1).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(1).Text, "NULL") & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(2).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(2).Text, "NULL") & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(3).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(3).Text, "NULL") & "','" & orderby & "','" & Val(IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(5).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, Val(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(5).Text), 0)) & "','" & IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(6).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(6).Text, "NULL") & "','" & Val(IIf(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(7).Text IsNot DBNull.Value, Val(lvReportFormat2.Items(ctr).SubItems(7).Text), 0)) & "')")
                ctr = ctr + 1
                orderby = orderby + 1
            Loop

               EXIT SUB

        Next
```